# Do links have default inertial values?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My model has two links, connected by a revolute joint.  I apply a torque via SetForce() and the second link accelerates relative to the first as one would expect.  The model.sdf only provides collision and visual information for the links.  Why does the link not have infinite acceleration if I've not specified inertial values?  Does Gazebo use some default inertial values if none are specified?

After adding large  values to the model.sdf the link accelerates more slowly than before, which sort of adds weight (get it?) to the case that Gazebo has default values for these parameters.  If so, do you know what they are and where I can find more information about topics like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12777/do-links-have-default-inertial-values?/) by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 165 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes it does, it's the identity matrix (`ixx` == `iyy` == `izz` == 1). You can see the default values in the SDF source code [for example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/753c70f286d59790160cf458ad18fa322def0691/sdf/1.6/inertial.sdf?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

You can also see the inertia values for your link during simulation on the left panel under `link` -> `inertial`. You can also right-click the model and choose `View` -> `Inertia` and you'll see a pink box representing the inertia for each link (see more information on [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8792/center-of-mass-block-is-larger-than-model/) question)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0